# Как включить поддержку filetables?

Tags: sql-server

Была установлена MS SQL Server Dev, следом установил Management Studio. В настройках сервера включил filestream, как сказано на офф. сайте:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Создал новую базу данных и хотел создать файловую группу, но не могу этого сделать. А без нее не могу создать таблицу. В чем может быть проблема?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Конфигурацию обновили `EXEC sp_configure filestream_access_level, 2  
RECONFIGURE`?

Comment: @vikolyada да...

Comment: В свойствах сервера что отображается в параметре `filestream access level`?

Comment: @vikolyada Включен полный доступ

Comment: Попробуйте через t-sql добавить — `alter database passoffice
add filegroup fsPassoffice contains filestream;
go`. Какую ошибку выдает?

Comment: @vikolyada Сообщение 5591, уровень 16, состояние 3, строка 1 Функция FILESTREAM отключена.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58246/discussion-between-vikolyada-and--).

Comment: А вы точно конфигурируете нужный инстанс, а не какой-то ещё? `select @@servicename` что возвращает?

Comment: @i-one MSSQLSERVER

Comment: да, тот же (если всё это на одном хосте), что и на скриншоте конфигуратора. странно, странно.

Comment: @i-one вот она проблема https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_server_team/filestream-issues-with-sql-server-on-windows-10-creators-update/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выяснили причину [в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58246/discussion-between-vikolyada-and--). Проблема в Window 10 Creators Update. [Описание от MSSQL Tiger Team](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_server_team/filestream-issues-with-sql-server-on-windows-10-creators-update/).

Возможные решения:

- поменять аккаунт из под которого запускается служба SQL Server на LocalSystem;
- поменять аккаунт из под которого запускается служба SQL Server на доменного пользователя с правами локального администратора на машине;
- если для запуска используется учетная запись `NT SERVICE\MSSQL$InstanceName`, то убедиться что у неё есть права локального администратора;
- деинсталировать Creators Update и вернуться на предыдущий билд Windows 10.

Comment: Первое решение заработало.